# Get part of string up to a point

Tags: java, string

So I'm looking to get the first numbers of an IP. Let's say I have something like 255.35.54.34. I want to get the first part of numbers up until the first period. How would I do this in Java? So it'd leave me with 255.

Comment: is it coming in as a string?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `String` class. You can use a couple of methods to accomplish this:

1. the `indexof(...)` method will give you the offset of the "."
2. the `substring(...)` method will allow you to get a string using the above offset

Or another option is to use the `split(...)` method to get an array of all four IP values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split()` method with a period as the argument. This will split the string along periods and give you a String[].

Then get the values just as you would from a normal array by using a subscript. In your case index 0 will get you the value

```
String ip = "255.255.255.255";
String[] splitIP = ip.split(".");
String required = splitIP[0];
```

Comment: -1 already suggested 8 minutes earlier. No need to clutter the forum with duplicate suggestions.

Comment: maybe I should post an SSCCE or a snippet

Comment: I would let the OP learn how to read the API at write the code themselves.

Answer (score 0):

As @camickr says, you can use `indexOf` and `substring` thus:

```
String ipAddress = "192.168.1.9";
System.out.println(ipAddress.substring(0, ipAddress.indexOf('.')));
```

This will print "192"

Comment: -1 As you say the suggestion has already been given. The OP can learn to read the API and write code on their own if we point them in the right direction.

Comment: So why didn't you just provide a link to the API, then?  I'm just adding a bit more value to your answer, don't take it personally, we're all just trying to help.

Comment: Because every programmer should have a link to the API handy. You can't program if you don't have access to the API. By forcing the OP to read the API they may also find other methods that will be helpful to them in the future. `we're all just trying to help.` - "Give somebody a fish they eat for a day. Teach somebody to fish they eat for life".

Comment: Your point is valid, but examples do help people learn and put API methods in context.  It's unreasonable to mark answers as "not useful" when they provide examples that augment your own.

Comment: Agreed examples help and that is what the forum or the web is for. Once you read the API you try to write the code. If you have problems, then you can now search the forum or the web for existing examples that use the suggested methods. There is no need to continually provide examples. Let people develop some basic problem solving skills, without us spoon feeding the code. The OP can always ask a follow up question showing the code they used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways :

One is that you use `String.split()` method, and other is to using `StringTokenizer` class.

**Using String.split() :**

```
String ip = "255.1.2.3";
String[] splitIP = ip.split("\\.");
String required = splitIP[0];
System.out.println(required);
```

Here \\ is required,oherwise it will throw an exception

**Using `StringTokenizer` :**

```
        String ip = "255.1.2.3";
        StringTokenizer tk=new StringTokenizer(ip,".");            
        while (tk.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {            
            System.out.println(tk.nextToken());
            break;
        }
```

Hope this will help you..